# Powershell Script, 2x variable in foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm losing my mind. I have to confess I'm a typical copy-paste non-scripting guy, stand here with something new I cannot solve. I want to work with ocrmypdf.exe where I have to read a network-folder for PDFs and put it on a subfolder.

ocrmypdf works simple: ocrmypdf.exe

I have 3 variables like:

```
$source = @(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\OCR\*.pdf') # <-- here are my files, filtered for pdfs
$destname = "X:\ocr\done" #destination-folder where the pdf-files should be written in
$destfiles = foreach ($file in $source) {"$destname\$($file.name)"} # <--- destination path + the same source-file-name
```

when I have to run a command-exe in Powershell, I should run it like

```
Foreach ($a in $source)
{

& $command $param

}
```

where $command and $param is (not) something like this:

```
$command = 'ocrmypdf.exe'
$param = '$source', '$destfiles'
```

but as I already know this is not working because the foreachloop can not work with my variables.

Could someone please help me to solve this? Yes my laziness reading a powershell-book comes over and over me now, but I try my luck anyway :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can supply as many arguments to a command invocation as you want:

```
$source = @(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\OCR\*.pdf')
$destname = "X:\ocr\done" 
$command = 'ocrmypdf.exe'

foreach ($file in $source) {
    $sourcePath = $file.FullName
    $destPath   = Join-Path $destname $file.name

    # pass both arguments to command
    & $command $sourcePath $destPath
}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast Mathias, give me a try :)